# bind rows of tibbles present in nested list

Tags: r, dplyr

I generated `mylist` which contains three tibbles.

After creating mylist, how can I create three tibbles `A_complete`, `B_complete` and `C_complete` by binding rows all As, Bs, Cs respectively of mylist.

```
mylist <- list()
for (iter in 1:10)
{
  mylist[[iter]] <- list(A = tibble(x = runif(5)),
                         B = tibble(x = rep("B", 2)),
                         C = tibble(x = 0:iter))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a good use for `purrr::transpose()`. Here's a simple tidyverse solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
complete_data = mylist %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  map(reduce, bind_rows)
```

Output:

```
> complete_data$A
# A tibble: 50 x 1
        x
    <dbl>
 1 0.905 
 2 0.102 
 3 0.923 
 4 0.504 
 5 0.187 
 6 0.945 
 7 0.0668
 8 0.596 
 9 0.131 
10 0.220 
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Similarly, `complete_data$B` and `complete_data$C` are available.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply`,

```
A_complete = lapply(mylist, function(x) x[['A']]) %>% bind_rows()
B_complete = lapply(mylist, function(x) x[['B']]) %>% bind_rows()
C_complete = lapply(mylist, function(x) x[['C']]) %>% bind_rows()
```